# Created By, Edited By, Date Created, Date Modified properties for each entity in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design, metadata, audit

I need these properties for each entity in my application. How can I implement this using DDD principles?

Similarly what if I wanted administrators to be able to make comments against each entity?

Comment: Why `java` and `C#` tag together?

Comment: Because syntax is somewhat similar and if someone needs to provide an example I am happy for it to be in either of these languages.

Comment: Concept is same in `java` and `C#` and not syntax.

Comment: I am well aware but I will remove one of the languages since it seems to be bothering you.

Comment: Could use the language-agnostic tag

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, use a common layer supertype for all of your classes that enculapses auditing.  From the P of EAA book:

> It's not uncommon for all the objects in a layer to have methods you don't want to have duplicated throughout the system. You can move all of this behavior into a common Layer Supertype.

It is then easy to update these fields as needed.

Another possibility, which is probably a bit cleaner, is to add audit logging to your repositories, as these things are clearly infrastructure concerns.  In particular, if "edited by" users have no representation in your domain but rather are "users" of your application.

Your repository implementations could, for example, store audit logs (created by, modified by, commands) in a separate audit log table in the database.

Comment: I was originally heading down the layer super type route although I felt it wasn't really clean so was seeing if there were alternatives. I also stumbled across something like this: http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/creating-an-audit-log-using-nhibernate-events.html but there are two issues with that: 1. The identifiers of all my entities must be of type  GUID. 2. Some entities will only be editable by the author that created them. I am suspecting that I only really have one option and that's the layer super type route or am I not understanding something?

Comment: With Entity Framework, the approach @Alexander Langer describes can be accomplished by declaring audit fields in an audit layer supertype, which all entities inherit from and then overwriting the DbContext.SaveChanges method to set the audit fields for entities marked as added/changed by the ChangeTracker. If using NHibernate something similar should be possible.

Comment: this is a pure infrastructure concern. why not have a db trigger that updates these fields? using EF 6 you can use an interceptor to set the current user for the session and access this from within your trigger.